# Amazon EC2 configuration for sending mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am using Amazon EC2 as my server to host my project developed using Codeigniter , all the things are working fine but i am facing a probelm that when i am sending a mail through this then it shows that mail is coming from www-data rather than my domain say www.demo.com and i am not able to understand where the problem is .

i am using gmail smtp and following is my header information

```
        ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.gmail.com");
        $to = "myid@gmail.com";
        $message = "<html>.......";
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' . $email . "\r\n" . phpversion();
        $subject = "Trabsport Query:-";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

so kindly help my to so that it can be solved

Comment: You want to send from your EC2 instance yet you set the SMTP server to `smtp.gmail.com`? Try removing the `ini_set()`, also what does the `$email` variable look like? Post all of your code please.

Comment: $email is a variable that is having email id of recipient and i have removed ini_set() function but still having same problem .......

Comment: `$email` should not be the recipient as its in the `From` header. Please post all your code.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have opened the respective ports in your security group.

Answer (score 0):

If your project are developed on codeigniter, i recommend you to use native codeigniter functions. [Email Class: CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)